# Facebook Resumable upload feature throws NotAuthorizedError exception

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am testing resumable api but after generating the upload session Id using user access token and pushing png data as file data, I am getting b'{"debug_info":{"retriable":false,"type":"NotAuthorizedError","message":"User not authorized to perform this request"}}'

my request looks like this
'https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/'+parsed['id'],
headers={'Authorization': 'OAuth'+access_token, 'file_offset': '0'}, files=file

Comment: There needs to be a space between `OAuth` and the access token value in the `Authorization` header, looks like you might have concatenated it without one?